# ¿Por qué no puedo llamar a una capa que ya está referenciada?

Tags: c#

Chicos tengo 2 horas buscando como solucionar este problema (Ja, que novato soy xd) y no puedo logro resolverlo.
Mi caso es que cuando hago referencia de una capa en otra, cuando trato de llamar a esa capa, no funciona.

[image: Aquí se observa que hice la referencia]

[image: Pero cuando la llamo en la capa de datos, ni me aparece]

Comment: El namespace dentro de Capa controlador si es el mismo? Tambien hay que compilarlo capa a capa, y fijarse si no tienes referencias circulares, a veces no genera la referencia por ese detalle.

Comment: TE AMO MI AMOL. Gracias funcionó, fue error mío